# Copying file using scp to non-existing local directory - misleading error message

Tags: linux, bash, scp, openssh

I'm writing a shell script for copying a file from a remote host to a local directory using `scp`. In case the target directory does not exist, I'm getting a misleading error message. i.e.:

```
scp user@remote-host:/path/to/existing/file /local/non-existing/directory/
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
/local/non-existing/directory/: Is a directory
```

which is puzzling... I would expect something like:

```
Directory /local/non-existing/directory/ does not exist
```

1. Does it make sense to anybody or is it just me?
2. Do you think it is a defect in scp?
3. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, is it the same in other operating systems?

Comment: Show output of `file /local/non-existing/directory/`.

Comment: `/path/to/existing/file` is a valid file on the remote host. `/local/non-existing/directory/` is a local path that does not exist.

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour). [Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Bug

Found the [related bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/18757). It seems to be fixed in Ubuntu 14.04.5 (openssh  1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.8)

There's an explanation on a [Redhat bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1142223) :

> This problem is also in original openSSH and appears when you try to
>   copy something into non-existing directory with existing parent
>   directory. There is missing check for this boundary condition. Error
>   message is thrown when scp process tries to write into above mentioned
>   file, but this file ends with slash (which is interpretation for
>   directory) and this is the reason for current error message.

## Original answer

Cannot reproduce (tested on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS and Linux Mint 17)

- If `/local/non-existing/directory` doesn't exist, `scp` fails with :

  ```
  /local/non-existing/directory: No such file or directory
  ```
- If `/local/existing/directory` exist, `scp` copies `file` to `/local/existing/directory/file`
- If `remote-host:/path/to/existing/file` is a directory, `scp` fails with :

  ```
  scp: file: not a regular file
  ```

## Troubleshooting

```
ssh user@remote-host "file /path/to/existing/file"
```

should give you information about the remote file (or possibly directory).

```
file /local/non-existing/directory/
```

should give you information about the local directory

```
mkdir -p /local/non-existing/directory/
```

wil recursively create the directory, and any parent if necessary.

After `mkdir -p`, if `file` is really a file and `/local/non-existing/directory/` is really a directory, your `scp` command should work.

Comment: What O/S are you on?

Comment: See update, 14.04.5

Comment: I'm not trying to troubleshoot it, since I already know that the local non-existing directory is the issue. I'm just puzzled by the misleading error message.

Comment: Still. Does it work after creating the `/local/non-existing/directory/`?

Comment: Yes, it does :::

Comment: Found the related bug. See update